# NPM's Live Server not allowing local files and folders in HTML file

Tags: html, powershell, hyperlink, npm-live-server

I have already asked this on the `live-server` [issue log](https://github.com/tapio/live-server/issues/409) but haven't received any response so I will try on here as well.

I'm trying to `a href` to a local folder in my HTML file. Typically I would do something like this: `<a href="C:\Users\aa\Desktop ....>`.

If I just open `index.html` with chrome using `start chrome (ls index.html).fullname` in a Powershell command line, I'm able to navigate to the link and view the contents of the folder.

However if I start Live Server on the same file using `live-server index.html` and navigate to the server instance using chrome, the link to my local folder does not work.

I've also noticed similar behavior when embedding images using `<img src ... >`, namely that the images are rendered when opening the file directly with Chrome, but not when connecting to the Live Server instance.

How can I get live-server to allow local folders/files?

Comment: REad following : https://github.com/tapio/live-server#live-server

Comment: You need to use NTFS protocol instead of FILE protocol.  NFTS is used to get files from a network drive using tow backslashes and machine name like \\myserver\path.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks. Any idea how I can  get the NTFS protocol to work on my local machine? I've tried something like `<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/images/test.png" alt="test" />` but it didn't work.

Comment: Windows should automatically support NFTS.  The local and remote machines must be in the same group so that credentials can be shared.  It is similar protocol to mounting a network drive on the machine.